# I'm uncomfortable with the 'myths' tag

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, scope

As per the title.  The tag [myths](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myths) seems inherently opposed to the site's identity as one which is aligned with traditional Judaism, which does not generally view traditional Jewish beliefs as being mythological.  Is there a better word that might be used for the concept being conveyed?  Should the tag not be used at all?  Should I not be so sensitive?

For what it's worth, the tag is used five times:  [Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/249/do-you-have-to-close-the-window-if-someones-cold), and I confess I don't see how it applies.  [Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5165/yushkas-bris-aniversary), where I do see how it applies, I think, but then any question seeking a Jewish perspective on non-Jewish beliefs might be eligible for this tag, and it seems that those questions are not in j.se's scope.  Finally, there are [three](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/882/geihinom-and-gan-eden) [old](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/892/sheidim-servant-of-satan-death-on-sight-duck-feet) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/989/36-hidden-tzadikim) by [one user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/114/shyk) that seem, at least to me, to have the agenda I'm reading from this tag in the first place.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with "myths" either but am also at a loss for how I would tag the question about the lamed-vavniks or the one about what sheidim look like.  Maybe "legends"?  ("Aggadah" would be too general, IMO.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I don't necessary agree with you that Aggadah would be too general.

Comment: I think you are confusing the traditional meaning of the word myth ("A myth is, broadly, any worldview-based traditional story, or collection or study thereof" (from [here](http://goo.gl/0kZkm))) and a later common/slang usage to mean falsehood (similar to how the meaning of awesome has changed with time). IMO the traditional/technical meaning is quite applicable to Judaism, and is used as such in various academic or formal English writings. See for instance [this article](http://goo.gl/EvQdY) and particularly [these](http://goo.gl/my5oN) [two](http://goo.gl/gUUkA) sections in it.

Comment: Related https://english.stackexchange.com/q/420366/19365

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps an [tag:urban-legends] tag, which doesn't have any other meanings (traditional or slang) attached to it?

Answer (score 4):

For all the questions listed above except ["Geihinom and Gan Eden"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/882), "myths" seems to be used to mean "urban legends" or the like: things that many people speak of but the questioner doubts the veracity of. In other words, it's used the same way [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) is.

So one solution would be to merge it into [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) as a synonym and write a good summary for [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) so that people don't use it for other myth-related questions. (And de-tag "Geihinom and Gan Eden".)

That leaves open a separate question, viz whether [sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sources) is necessary at all. But it's a good plan for the time being IMO.

Comment: I remember a discussion a while ago in which there was a consensus that [tag:sources] is superfluous. I think there is a distinction between it (very broad, possibly universally so) and the tag in question. [tag:myths] is for things about which there is a reasonable assumption to be baseless.

Comment: @WAF: Well, `myths` is for things about which there's an assumption that they're baseless. Its reasonableness will generally be debatable. (This very question seems to be based on such debatedness.) As to `sources`, I don't recall the discussion you mention, but I have no problem with getting rid of the tag.

Comment: (See my comment to the question.)